# В двухстрочном элементе списка иконка плюсик съезжает

Tags: html, css

Необходимо, чтобы иконки оставались на уровне верхней строки списка, но если появляется вторая строка то плюсик съезжает на ее уровень.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 100px;
  background: #929292;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: "Arial";
}

input {
  font-size: 1em;
}

ol.tree {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

li label {
  padding-left: 37px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url("https://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_tree/folder-horizontal.png") no-repeat 15px 2px;
  display: block;
}

li input {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  left: -0.5em;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li input+ol {
  height: 1em;
  margin: -16px 0 0 -44px;
  background: url("https://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_tree/toggle-small-expand.png") no-repeat 40px 0;
}

li input+ol>li {
  display: none;
  margin-left: -14px !important;
  padding-left: 1px
}

li.file {
  margin-left: -1px !important;
}

li.file a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 21px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: url("https://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_tree/document.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}

li input:checked+ol {
  height: auto;
  margin: -21px 0 0 -44px;
  padding: 25px 0 0 80px;
  background: url("https://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_tree/toggle-small.png") no-repeat 40px 5px;
}

li input:checked+ol>li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 0.063em;
}

li input:checked+ol>li:first-child {
  margin: 0 0 0.125em;
}
```

```html
<ol class="tree">
  <li>
    <label for="two">Две <br> строки</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="two" />
    <ol>


      <li class="file"><a href="">menu-1</a></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="one">Одна строка</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="one" />
    <ol>
      <li>

        <li class="file"><a href="">menu-2</a></li>
    </ol>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например через псевдо элементы:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 100px;
  background: #929292;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: "Arial";
}

input {
  font-size: 1em;
}

ol.tree {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

li label {
  padding-left: 37px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url("https://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_tree/folder-horizontal.png") no-repeat 15px 2px;
  display: block;
}

li input {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: 2px;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index:2;
}

li input+ol {
  height: 1em;
  margin: -16px 0 0 -44px;
}

li input+ol:before {
  content: '';
  background: url("https://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_tree/toggle-small-expand.png") no-repeat 0 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  top: 2px;
  left: -4px;
  position: absolute;
}

li input+ol>li {
  display: none;
  margin-left: -14px !important;
  padding-left: 1px
}

li.file {
  margin-left: -1px !important;
}

li.file a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 21px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: url("https://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_tree/document.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}

li input:checked+ol {
  height: auto;
  margin: -21px 0 0 -44px;
  padding: 25px 0 0 80px;
}

li input:checked+ol:before {
  background: url("https://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_tree/toggle-small.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}

li input:checked+ol>li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 0.063em;
}

li input:checked+ol>li:first-child {
  margin: 0 0 0.125em;
}
```

```html
<ol class="tree">
  <li>
    <label for="two">Две <br> строки</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="two" />
    <ol>


      <li class="file"><a href="">menu-1</a></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="one">Одна строка</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="one" />
    <ol>
      <li>

        <li class="file"><a href="">menu-2</a></li>
    </ol>
    </li>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но при этом съезжает курсор

Comment: поправила, если ответ вам помог, отметьте его ответом

Comment: Громадное спасибо!

Comment: Я новичок. Подскажите пожалуйста как это - отметить ответом?

Comment: спасибо, вижу вы разобрались)